# Expand Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: analysis, polynomials

The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that  polynomial equation of degree $n$ can be written as

$$
p(z) = a_0(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)
$$

How would one go about expanding this expression and what would the expansion look like?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $n$, with roots $z_1,...,z_n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: You might be interested in Vieta's fornulas. They relate the roots of the polynomial to its coefficients.

Comment: I would recommend, instead of just looking it up, expanding out small degree expressions.  Group the terms and factor out the powers of z.  Then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at small powered expressions, you can find the pattern nicely.  For example,

$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=z^2-(z_1+z_2)z+z_1z_2$$

$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)=z^3-(z_1+z_2+z_3)z^2+(z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_1z_3)z-z_1z_2z_3$$

Note the sum of the roots is the coefficient for the term of degree 1 less than that of the number of roots.  Note the constant term is the product of the roots...and certainly if you multiply by a constant $a_0$, what would happen there?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients happen to be the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)  in the roots $z_1,\dots,z_n$.